# My app stops responding when I run it on the Profiling mode

Tags: android, memory-leaks, profiler

I'm having a few OutOfMemory errors on long running sessions of my Android App. To find the cause I'm trying to use the Android Studio Profiler but it stops working and freezes the app within 10 seconds of use.

There's a screenshot of the Android Studio Screen. It logs the activities within the first seconds, then it just freezes the app and stops logging anything -> https://ibb.co/QXLhqnz

Last lines of my logcat reads (the last lines keep repeating with increasing time, I changed my package name)

```
2019-04-09 08:42:41.151 19728-20399/br.com.xxxxx V/StudioProfiler: Live memory tracking enabled.
2019-04-09 08:42:41.151 19728-20399/br.com.xxxxx V/StudioProfiler: JNIEnv not attached
2019-04-09 08:42:41.483 19728-20399/br.com.xxxxx V/StudioProfiler: Loaded classes: 8894
2019-04-09 08:42:51.688 19728-20399/br.com.xxxxx E/zygote: E[0]:Timed out waiting for threads to suspend(br.com.xxxxx), waited for 10.000s
2019-04-09 08:43:01.689 19728-20399/br.com.xxxxx E/zygote: E[0]:Timed out waiting for threads to suspend(br.com.xxxxx), waited for 20.000s
2019-04-09 08:43:11.689 19728-20399/br.com.xxxxx E/zygote: E[0]:Timed out waiting for threads to suspend(br.com.xxxxx), waited for 30.000s
```

Any help appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce this reliably?  If so, can you provide exact reproduction steps/a sample project?

Comment: I'm sorry, not anymore. I changed jobs a while ago and have no access to that code anymore.. It's been 11 months now :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: @RyanM I always can reproduce this ,  mainly on Android 8.0

Comment: @kaitian521 Can you reproduce in a freshly created project on another computer?

Comment: @Enselic I let my college have a try, he can reproduce too

Comment: I think this is a bug. but I'm not sure. however, I think you should update your android studio to the latest version. maybe it will be fixed :)

Comment: The fact that you and your colleague are able to reproduce the issue does not help much, while none of us is able to reproduce it. Most likely leakage is to blame, which one can only assume, without the least code provided.

Comment: I upgrade Androdi Studio to 4,1, too crashed...

Comment: @kaitian521 Try with Android Studio 3.6.2 once (the leak nevertheless needs to be fixed).

Comment: I got this on Studio 4.0

Comment: also got this crash on 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android Studio Profiler might not be the proper tool for the task. First identify possible memory leaks with [LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary) and fix them,
then you should be able to use the Profiler, without having stalled/killed threads. Without the least code provided, this might be the best possible answer.

The reason for this behavior likely is, that the ART kills off stalled threads, while the Profiler keeps waiting for them to respond, which obviously will never happen, because they don't exist anymore.

The error message comes from ART, just see [`thread_list.cc`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/thread_list.cc). On Dalvik VM it might behave differently (most likely force-close due to OOM, or it may crash the VM). That might be worth a try. Stepping into it while profiling might also be an option, but it's by far not as handy as LeakCanaray.

---

**Update**: The Android Studio 3.6.2 release notes state:

> Improved memory leak detection for your Activities and Fragments when using Profilers.

Comment: it worked for me on my android 8 device after updating from android 3.6.1 to 3.6.3 i assume it was a bug

Comment: it worked for me on my android 7 device after updating from android 3.6.3 to 4.0 i assume it was a bug