# my app totally freezes when I turn android studio profiler on, so i am unable to view network traffic

Tags: android, android-studio, network-traffic

I want to find out how much data my app is sending but my app freezes and stops reacting to my inputs when i turn android studio profiler on. is this a known issue? I havnt seen any posts on this. is there an alternative to view the network traffic of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just worked after updating android studio from 3.6.1 to 3.6.3 i assume this was a bug. i still have to check my app for memory leaks but i somehow doubt this was the reason. on i other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55592239/10637400) i found this was affecting particularly android 8 devices. hope this helps other people with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you run your app on a device that has low memory, so when you try to use profiler (which take amount of device memory) your device run out of memory.

if you run it on emulator try making a new AVD with More RAM size than one you tried

Comment: i mean when the i start running the profiler it actually works for a bit and the memory usage of my app is not excessive. also my phone has 3gb of ram which seems enough

Comment: try using systrace instead of network profiler, check doc: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/tracing/on-device

Comment: sadly, im using android 8 but this indeed seems like it would be an alternative